# WP Pagination Loop not working in custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Pagination loop not working in custom theme Home page template. Shows same content in all pages.

You can also suggest me some other code to fix the issue.

```
<?php 
// clear any other queries that may be in use!
wp_reset_query();
// check for $_GET paged value 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// setup post arguments
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'paged' => $paged, );
// run our query
query_posts($args);
// start loop
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  // if you use the <!-- more --> in your posts.
  global $more;
  $more = 0;
?>
   <div class="post">
     <?php the_title(); ?>
   </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
   <?php next_posts_link('Next'); ?>
   <?php previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
   <div><h2>Nothing found</h2><p>No posts found for that query</p></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe it had some other issues, couldn't make the pagination work on the theme.

Then fixed the issue by using a ajax pagination plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If above answer wont work for you, use WP_Query instead of query_posts.

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'paged'          => $paged
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

If the pagination is broken on a static front page you have to add the "paged" parameter this way:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

query_posts() isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. Use WP_Query instead. It accepts the same parameters as query_posts does. Be aware that neither of these methods is the most efficient way to alter the default query. In fact, either method can also be responsible for breaking pagination.

If your theme is using either of these methods to query the main loop, you can replace it with the preferred way, that is to say, hooking into 'pre_get_posts' and altering the main query by using is_main_query(). This way is faster and more reliable because the query for the main loop is altered before the posts are retrieved from the database.

For example, lets say your theme queries the main loop like this on your home page and the pagination is not working:

```
<?php 
// clear any other queries that may be in use!
wp_reset_query();
// check for $_GET paged value 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// setup post arguments
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'paged' => $paged, );
// run our query
query_posts($args);
// start loop
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  // if you use the <!-- more --> in your posts.
  global $more;
  $more = 0;
?>
   <div class="post">
     <?php the_title(); ?>
   </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
   <?php next_posts_link('Next'); ?>
   <?php previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
   <div><h2>Nothing found</h2><p>No posts found for that query</p></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Remove the query_posts part from your code:

```
<?php 
// clear any other queries that may be in use!
wp_reset_query();
// check for $_GET paged value 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// setup post arguments
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'paged' => $paged, );
// run our query
query_posts($args);
?>
```

And add the query for your home page back in your theme's functions.php file:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  // do not alter the query on wp-admin pages and only alter it if it's the main query
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){

    // alter the query for the home and category pages 

    if(is_home()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 7);
    }

    if(is_category()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }

  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

You can use conditional tags to target the pages where we want to alter the query. Like,

```
// alter the query for the Movies category page 
if(is_home() || is_front_page){
  $query->set('posts_per_page', 7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
   // Define custom query parameters
   $args = array(  'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged );
    $custom_query_args = array( $args );

  // Instantiate custom query
  $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

  // Pagination fix
  $temp_query = $wp_query;
  $wp_query   = NULL;
  $wp_query   = $custom_query;

// Output custom query loop
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post();
                 ?>
             <div class="blog-post">
                 <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail'); ?>

   <?php  endwhile;
endif;
// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

echo "<div class='blog-nav'>";

// Custom query loop pagination
previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' );
next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $custom_query->max_num_pages );

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'total' => $custom_query->max_num_pages
) );

// Reset main query object
echo "</div>";
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
```